# Limit point of a subset of a compact set

Tags: general-topology

In a [book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-quantitative-finance) in a chapter about sets I see the following proposition:

If $\{x_n\} \subset E \subset X$, where $\{x_n\}$ is a countably or unaccountably infinite set, $E$ is compact, $X$ is a metric space, then $\{x_n\}$ has a limit point $x \in E$.

The proposition seems supper trivial to me: indeed, any point of a set is its limit point, so $\forall x \in \{x_n\} \subset E$ is a limit point.

Am I not understanding the "message" of the proposition or it is just formulated sloppily?

If latter, could you please provide a better formulation?

Answer (score 2):

A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $E$ if every open set containing $x$ also contains at least one point of $E$ other than $x$.

Since you are working in a metric space, this means that every open set containing $x$ must in fact contain infinitely many points of $E$.

Comment: I see, this definition is in line with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+point, but in the book the author gives another (wrong?) definition: $x$ is a limit point of $E$ if $\forall r B_r(x) \bigcap E \ne \emptyset$, where $B_r(x)$ is an open ball around $x$ of radius $r$.

Comment: That isn't the standard definition. It should probably read $$\forall r  (B_r(x) \setminus \{x\}) \cap E \not= \emptyset.$$

Comment: @SergeyZykov: That would be the definition of "Adherent point of $E$". The set of adherent points of $E$ is the same as the closure of $E$ and is the union of $E$ with the set of its limit points.